# Como se descobre o termo X da sequência de Fibonacci?

Tags: c#, .net, fibonnaci

Tenho que fazer um programa em C# que receba um número `X` que vai ser o termo da sequência e o imprima na tela.

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

Eu ia responder "calculando cada termo até onde você quer". Já estava pensando em em fazer uma solução recursiva e outra repetitiva. Mas aí me veio a ideia de procurar se alguém já tinha pensando em uma solução melhor. E achei isto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018473/221800) no SO (e resolvi pelas formas mais tradicionais também):

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) WriteLine($"{Fib(i)}, {FibIte(i)}, {FibRec(i)}");
    }
    static int Fib(int n) {
        double sqrt5 = Sqrt(5);
        double p1 = (1 + sqrt5) / 2;
        double p2 = -1 * (p1 - 1);
        return (int)((Pow(p1, n) - Pow(p2, n)) / sqrt5);
    }
    static int FibIte(int n) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp + b;
        }
        return a;
    }
    static int FibRec(int n) => n < 2 ? n : FibRec(n - 1) + FibRec(n - 2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PFQxC3). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f5XiHP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Fibonacci.cs).

Comment: +1 pela solução que aproxima o número de ouro.